# Why tfpt.exe missing although TFS Power Tools installed?

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I am using Visual studio community 2017 on Windows 10, I installed TFS power tools 2011, 2013, 2015 (I read that previous Power Tools have been integrated into TFS 2017) but there are no tfpt.exe in any installation directory.

Comment: Which feature from tfpt are you looking for? Did you select the tool to be installed in the installation? Do you have Team Explorer 2015 or Team Explorer 2013 installed? It's a prerequisite for most of the power tools components. If you hadn't, repair/reinstall the matching power tools after installing.

Comment: See also: https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-power-tools-install-side-by-side/

Comment: I need to execute "tfpt uu" for files in a folder. I didn't select any other tool than selecting standard version while installation. I had not installed Team explorer 2015(Is it not default installed with vs2017?), I have installed it and reinstall TFS power tools but nothing changed, still no tfpt.exe.

Answer (score 6):

When you install Team Foundation Power Tools it will warn you, but won't block you when it doesn't detect the required version of Visual Studio. Each version is picky, so the TFPT 2015 will require Visual Studio 2015 and the TFPT 2013 will require you to install Visual Studio 2013.

It should be sufficient to install the Team Explorer of that version only, but if the installer still complains, you may need to install the full Visual Studio:

[image: Feature prerequisites needed]

There is no way to force the installation. Which is unfortunate, as in many cases it's enough to add the contents of the TeamFoundation Nuget Packages.

Upon successful installation of the power tools, including `tfpt.exe` should be found under:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\
```

If you're looking for Undo Unchanged, then you may also be interested in the [TFS Source Control Explorer Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-18397). It adds Undo-unchanged to the Pending Changes window in Visual Studio. There are versions available for every version of Visual Studio since 2010.

You could also consider switching to a Local Workspace, it automatically detects when a file is returned to its original state and will automatically mark it as Unchanged. You will lose the ability to lock files though. Some people hate that, for many, it's a blessing. I'll let you decide. For me, it was a nice step-up to switching to Git later.

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional info about TFS Source Control Explorer Extensions.  That was all I needed.  Amazing that a feature such as "Undo Unchanged" did not exist in VS 2017 to begin with.  pumpkinpuke.jpg.