# 'tfpt' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, tfs-power-tools

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2019, and I am not able to see the tfpt.exe. I tried to install Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools, but no luck.

Any guess?

Comment: Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools should install it. did you install the powershell module during the Power Tools installation?

Answer (score 1):

First please check if Visual Studio Team Explorer 2019 is installed. It's a prerequisite for most of the power tools components. Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812840/why-tfpt-exe-missing-although-tfs-power-tools-installed).

- Go to All downloads > Visual Studio 2019 > Visual Studio Team
  Explorer 2019 > Download

In addition, Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools could not be applicable to visual studio 2019. Please refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307522/team-foundation-server-power-tools-for-visual-studio-2019).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Let me check this and update you

Comment: I am not able to find the installer for Visual Studio Team Explorer 2019. It would be great if you can provide the link.